# How to benefit of the docker image cache when cloning a git repo

Tags: docker, docker-image

I have a private git repository that I have to add to my docker image. For that I clone it locally in the same directory with the `Dockerfile` and then use the following docker command:

`ADD my_repo_clone /usr/src/`

My repo has a version tag that I clone, `v1`. So the files that I clone are always the same.

The problem is that when I build this docker image I always get a **new** image instead of replacing the old one:

`docker build --rm -t "org_name/image_name" .`

Apparently, because the `ctime` of the files change, the docker cache is not seeing my files as identical so I get always a new image, which I want to avoid.

I tries to `touch` the cloned repo and change `atime` and `mtime` to be a fixed date, but it is still not enough.

How can I stop Docker (without changing Docker source code that computes the file hashes and building it again) from creating all the time new images.

Or how can I clone the repo during the image building process? (For this I need SSH forwarding since the repo is private, and I could also not make SSH agent forwarding work during an image build process)

Comment: do you need the actual git repository in your docker image, or would you be happy if you just have the files for the `v1` tag?

Comment: The files are OK as well.

Answer (score 0):

since you don't care about the repository itself and just need the files for tag `v1`, you could use [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) instead of `git clone` to produce a *tar* archive holding the files for tag `v1`.

Finally, the docker `ADD` directive to inject the archive into the image.

The *mtime* of the produced tar archive will be the time of the tag as documented:

> git archive behaves differently when given a tree ID versus when given a commit ID or tag ID. In the first case the current time is used as the modification time of each file in the archive. In the latter case **the commit time as recorded in the referenced commit object is used** instead.

---

try:

```
git archive --remote=https://my.git.server.com/myoproject.git refs/tags/v1 --format=tar > v1.tar
```